# Even spacing in multi-line text in matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-node

I have a tikz matrix of nodes.
The first column are "bullets" and the second column is the "text".

I would like each line of "text" to occupy the same height.
Unfortunately, variations in the actual text seem to change these heights - i.e., whether the text contains capital letters and/or descenders (like "g", "j", ..)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
mat/.style={draw=red, line width=1pt, rectangle, matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text width=5cm, 
%text width=5cm, text height=2ex, text depth=1ex,
nodes={draw=blue, line width=0.2pt, anchor=base}}]

% first matrix - single line
\matrix[mat,
column 1/.style={text width=3cm},
column 2/.style={text width=5cm},
] (single) at (0, 0) {
March 2020&txt\\
May 2019&txt\\
May 2018&txt\\
March 2017&txt\\
};

% second matrix - multi line
\matrix[mat, anchor=north west,
column 1/.style={text width=3cm},
column 2/.style={text width=5cm}] (multi) at (single.south west) {
Bullet A: & Notice the uneven spacing between the rows above. I want it to be even.\\
Bullet B: & The text in this matrix is multi-line. I want it to follow the same alignment, with respect to text height and depth, as the matrix above.\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the MWE above, I show how the spacing is uneven.
I have tried fixing this by setting `text height` and `text depth` (you can uncomment the line above to see my attempt).
While this fixes the issue in the first matrix (where the text is single-line) it completely ruins the second matrix.

Is there a setting that I can apply to both of these cases?
That way I don't have to worry about whether the text is single-line or multi-line.

Comment: This looks like a `tabular`, is there any reason to use `TikZ`? BTW, welcome to TeX-SX

Comment: @Ignasi - Thanks for the suggestion. I will try with `tabular` and report back if this meets my needs.